# Geometric interpretation of Hermite's identity

Tags: geometry, number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I came across an elegant interpretation of the well known reciprocity law for the floor function in the USSR problem book and I was wondering if there was a similar sort of interpretation for Hermite's identity;

Reciprocity law interpretation:

[image]
[image]

(I'm sorry if I'm not supposed to attach images for this kind of thing, but I honestly do not know how to explain it better than the book itself.)

I've seen both an elementary proof for Hermite's identity and one using the periodicity of the function $f(x)=[x]+\left[x+\dfrac{1}{n}\right]...+\left[x+\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right]-[nx]$. Does anyone have a proof that is more geometric in flavor, similar to the one above, for Hermite's identity?

Comment: Uh, just to be clear, by "Hermite's identity," do you mean the statement that the function f(x) defined in the last paragraph of your question is identically $0$ for all real $x$?  As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_identity ?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean

Comment: When I was a school boy, I met the following training problem in the book of problems of USSR all-Union mathematical competitions. Show that for each natural $n$ we have:

$$\lfloor n\rfloor+\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor+\dots+\lfloor \sqrt[n]{n}\rfloor=
\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor+\lfloor \log_3 n\rfloor+\dots+\lfloor \log_n n\rfloor.$$

Comment: Okay wow, that is amazing, I will try it out at once!

Comment: @AlexRavsky do you have a solution for your equality? I have been at it for a while now and I have made nearly no progress other than verifying it for the first 50 numbers using a calculator ):

Comment: Oops, sorry, the left hand side begins from $\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor$ instead of $\lfloor n\rfloor$. The solution was not provided in the book. But it is easy to see that each side of the equality is equal to $n-1$ plus the number of integer grid points $(x,y)$ where $2\le x,y\le n$ and $y^x\le n$.

Comment: Oh, I did not see that, thanks

Comment: I once posted here an algebraic proof of Hermite's identity. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @َAlex Ravsky: Is there a reference for the formula that you write? $\lfloor n\rfloor+\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor+\dots+\lfloor \sqrt[n]{n}\rfloor= \lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor+\lfloor \log_3 n\rfloor+\dots+\lfloor \log_n n\rfloor.
$

Comment: @Khosrotash Unfortunately, I have a reference only for the problem without its solution. Also I recall that the left hand side begins from $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$ instead of $\lfloor n\rfloor$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

First, let's call our variable $z$ instead of $x$ so we don't get the coordinate confused with the variable.  Then we're trying to prove:
$$\lfloor z\rfloor + \left\lfloor z + {1\over n}\right\rfloor + ... + \left\lfloor z + {(n-1)\over n}\right\rfloor = \lfloor nz\rfloor$$

Without loss of generality, assume $0 \le z < 1$.

Define a triangle $ABC$ with $A = (0,z)$, $B = (n,z)$, and $C = (n,z+1)$.  (See figure.)  We shall show that the number of integer-coordinate points inside the triangle is equal to both sides of what we're trying to prove, computed different ways.  Note that the $y$-coordinate is 1 for every integer-coordinate point inside the triangle.

The formula for the line $AC$ is $f(x) = z + {x\over n}$, so for an integer $x$ with $0\le x < n$, the number of integer-coordinate points with that $x$ value inside the triangle is $\lfloor z + {x\over n}\rfloor$.  Summing over integer-valued $x$ with $0\le x < n$, we get the left-hand side of our identity.

Let $x_0$ be the $x$-coordinate of the point on $AC$ with $y=1$.  Then $$1 =f(x_0) = z + {x_0\over n}$$
so
$$x_0 = n(1-z)$$
Counting to the right of $x_0$ along the line $y=1$, we see that the number of integer-coordinate points inside the triangle is $$\lfloor n-x_0\rfloor = \lfloor n - n(1-z)\rfloor$$
$$= \lfloor nz\rfloor$$

Comment: How does this generalize to $z>1$? Like, in the step where you noted that the number of integer coordinate points is $[z+1/n]$, that is indeed true for $z<1$ but for $z>1$, the number of points in that triangle will have to be summed over $[z+1/n]-[z]$.

Comment: Also, thanks for paying my question attention!

Comment: To _geometrically_ generalize to $z > 1$, instead of using a triangle, use a trapezoid with the lower edge the $x=0$ axis, so the count is the number of points in the rectangle below the triangle plus the number of points in the triangle.

Comment: Cognoscenti, my reputation on math.stackexchange.com is currently low enough that I can't comment on your question or solution.  I'll add more comments once my reputation score hits 50.

Comment: Could you try now? I awarded the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

For the case $z>1$, the following diagram applies;
[image]

Counting the integer points vertically inside the trapezium along $x=1,2,3...(n-1)$ yields the sum required on the LHS. Whereas, counting inside the rectangular region horizontally along $y=1,2,3...[z]$ yields $n[z]$ integer points. In the triangular region, there is only one horizontal line $y=[z+1]$ which corresponds to the point on the slanting line $x_0=n[z+1]-z$. Hence, the number of integer points in the triangular region are $[n-x_0]=[n+z-n[z+1]]$.

Hence, the RHS representing the number of integer points in the trapezoid counted horizontally becomes $n[z]+[n+z-n[z+1]]$. How does this simplify into $[nz]$? In fact, when I tried to simplify it, it became $[z]$ alone?

Comment: The line along the top of the trapezoid has formula $y = z + x/n$.  For $x_0$, we want $y = \lfloor z + 1 \rfloor$.  So $\lfloor z + 1 \rfloor = z + x_0/n$ or $$x_0 = n(\lfloor z + 1 \rfloor - z)$$.

Comment: Putting the fix from my previous comment into your next step, we get that the number of integer points inside the triangle is $$\lfloor n - x_0 \rfloor = \lfloor n - n(\lfloor z + 1\rfloor - z)\rfloor$$ $$= \lfloor n - n(\lfloor z \rfloor + 1 - z)\rfloor$$ $$= \lfloor n(z - \lfloor z\rfloor)\rfloor$$.  Shall I continue?

Comment: Ah shoot, I see my mistake, I wrote $x_0$ wrong. Thanks a lot @SteveSoule!